# база английских слов

Tags: база-данных, поиск-библиотек

мне нужна база английских слов и желательно с переводом на русский , где такую можно взять ?

после многочисленных проб парсинга слов с сайтов я набрал около 50к слов , но в них так много ошибок в переводе , что я решил сделать другую

Для моих нужд нужно около 300-400к слов с переводом . я видел много баз , но они меня не устраивали лишними словами "ZZZ" , "ABC" и так далее .

так же повторюсь , желателен ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ перевод , а не то , что я увидел в одной из баз Sport - скорость

формать записи , наверно , важен 
Мне нужен список слов в столбик )
например :
1) Eng word 
  на другой строчке translate
2) Eng word - translate
3) eng words /transcription/ - translate

Comment: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Comment: А кастомный формат записи  вы можете легко сформировать в ST3 из структурированного исходника правкой с использованием мультикурсора. Примеры есть на главной странице редактора и в множестве туторов.

Comment: @MikhailM , загляните в список этих слов и посмотрите , что там встречаются именно те слова , которые я не просил )
ABC , ZZZ 
2
1080
&c
10-point
10th
11-point
12-point
16-point
18-point
это вообще слова?

Comment: @andrey words_alpha.txt посмотри

Comment: @MikhailM a , aa ,aaa ,aaaa :DDDDDD
b , ba , c ca , серьезно?

Comment: a - артикль,
aa - Lava having a rough surface,
Ba = barium,
C = Celsius,
Ca = calcium

Comment: @MikhailM понял , извиняюсь )